# How to fill the shapes with color

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, flood-fill

I am new to Objective-C and iOS development. I have a view with some figures drawn by core drawing. Now I want to fill those shapes with color and I don't know the path or context of shape. Does Objective-C have any function like flood-fill or put-pixel so that by having only the stroke color I can fill any shape inside my view.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0);       
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();       
    CGFloat components[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0};      
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);     
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0,320);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);


    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 255, 0, 1.0);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 100, 100);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 150, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 200);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 150);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 100);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);

    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);

    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

This will make a circle and a square with some common region. I want a particular region to fill with color when a user taps that region.

Comment: Hi. Have you found a solution to this since you asked the question? I could use it too.

Answer (score 2):

So you are looking for flood fill in Objective C.

This is my implementation of Scan Line Flood Fill Algorithm.

[Github : UIImageScanlineFloodfill](https://github.com/Chintan-Dave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill)

If you want to learn basic of flood fill:

[Lode's Computer Graphics Tutorial Flood Fill](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html)

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Put your drawing code in the question and I can give you a specific answer.

Normally you just need to set a fill color using

```
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
```

And any shapes you draw your core graphics will be filled with that color automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:-

```
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
```

Comment: the thing is that i don't want to use context or path. I want a function similar to flood fill or put pixel in c

Comment: if you have to draw on any view you have to work with context.

Comment: here is a tutorial for you if you want to refer:-http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

Comment: drawing shapes is not the problem. The problem is to color them without the use of context or path, cause i don't know the context of the common region of the shapes. try my code and try to fill the common space of circle and square by taping inside that common region

Answer (score 0):

Core Graphics is closely tied to `UIView` and its `drawRect:` method and has a C interface. As you point out, you always draw in the current graphics context. I can think of 2 approaches: (1) When the user taps `myView`, set a property like `myView.pointTapped`, and in `drawRect:` find the shape to fill, set a fill color, and fill the closed path using *GGGeometry* methods.

There is an objective-C alternative: (2) Take a look at `UIBezierPath`. It's not as comprehensive as drawing in Core Graphics but it can be used in your `ViewController` implementation.